# How to build a scene with Curved World effect

Tags: scripting, shaders, shader-nodes, world

Is there a way to have a **curved world** like **Death Spank** or **Animal Crossing**?

This effect used to be called Rolling Log Effect (by Nintendo) also World Bending Effect is another name.

This effect is a world shader feature, not a modifier or mesh-base effect.

The whole idea is like a curved sight of camera instead of having straight one, the world elements are going behind the horizon like it rolls.

There are some tutorials for Unity, they do somethings with Graph shader there, semi-equal to World Shader of blender. But even any kind of script is appreciated too! XD

Examples: [left is Death Spank and Subway surfer (this features a vertical bending effect), right is Animal Crossing]

[image: ِDeath Spank and Subway Surfer]
[image: Animal Crossing]

I've found an article for this in Blender Artist forums and a user suggested a script, it is for version 2.1 of Blender I guess, and for the period software had Game engine feature, while it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I guess this could be done with a displacement shader.. Do you want the rotation in World Space (Fixed rolling log) or Camera Space (View-dependent) ?

Comment: Camera space (I guess), there is no mesh tessellation or deformation needed, mostly in video games I mentioned, where poly count matters, but here I want same result in Blender, which is a 3D design software.
If there be a solution, scene can be rendered fast in EEVEE, with an optimize low poly scene.